# Why NumberFormat working different for openjdk@11 and openjdk@17?

Tags: java, number-formatting, openjdk-11, openjdk-17

There is sample code (below).
Result of execution is different for jdk@11 and jdk@17.
Looks like white characters are different after formatting BigDecimal(1000) to String.
Finally result looks the same - BUT, it is not the same String (compare bytes and Base64.encoded).

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NumberFormatTest {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(1000);

        String result = numberFormat.format(value); // <-- HERE!

        System.out.println(result);
        byte[] bytes = result.getBytes();
        for( int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(bytes[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
    }

}
```

result for **jdk@11** is different than for **jdk@17**

result for jdk@11:

```
1 000,00 €
49, -62, -96, 48, 48, 48, 44, 48, 48, -62, -96, -30, -126, -84, 
McKgMDAwLDAwwqDigqw=
```

result for jdk@17:

```
1 000,00 €
49, -30, -128, -81, 48, 48, 48, 44, 48, 48, -62, -96, -30, -126, -84, 
MeKArzAwMCwwMMKg4oKs
```

jdk@11:

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0, mixed mode)
```

jdk@17:

```
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

System:

```
MacOS
Catalina 10.15.7
```

Is it expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the difference between the two versions is that the the grouping separator (between the `1` and the `0`) is U+00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE) in JDK 11, and U+202F (NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE) in JDK 17.

This is the expected behaviour. See this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225245) that was resolved as "not a problem".

From the discussions in the bug report:

> CLDR has changed the grouping separator for French in v34, from U+00A0 to U+202F:
> https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/34/delta/fr.html#Symbols
> JDK has been based on v35.1 since [JDK 13] b21